# changing background of elements in loop, then change hover color as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, background

```
$(function () {
    var forum = $('.main-content .statused tr'),
        i, 
    myColors = ["#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#8A4B08","#084B8A","#8A0868","#6A0888","#21610B","#8A0808","#0B4C5F","#5E610B","#210B61"],
    myHoverColors=["#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FF8000","#0080FF","#FF0080","#A901DB","#04B404","#FF0000","#01DFD7","#FFFF00","#4000FF"];
    for (i = 0; i < myColors.length; i++) {
        if (!forum[i]) return;
        forum[i].style.backgroundColor = myColors[i];
    }
});
```

The above code works (thought it did now it is not look at bottom) perfectly fine thanks to someone here on S.O.
What i added to it though is the myHoverColors, and what I am trying to do is change the hover color just like I did with the main background. Here was my try which ruined the entire code

```
$(function () {
    var forum = $('.main-content .statused tr'),
        i, 
myColors = ["#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#FFF","#8A4B08","#084B8A","#8A0868","#6A0888","#21610B","#8A0808","#0B4C5F","#5E610B","#210B61"],
myHoverColors=["#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FFE8E9","#FF8000","#0080FF","#FF0080","#A901DB","#04B404","#FF0000","#01DFD7","#FFFF00","#4000FF"];
    for (i = 0; i < myColors.length; i++) {
        if (!forum[i]) return;
        forum[i].style.backgroundColor = myColors[i];
    }

//my hover try
$(forum).hover(function() {
   for (i = 0; i < myHoverColors.length; i++) {
         if (!forum[i]) return;
          forum[i].style.backgroundColor = myHoverColors[i];
     }
  });
});
```

What it does is when you hover it completely destroys the code altogether. And I believe this is because I am trying to change the color like I did in the regular code above. Does anyone have suggestions on how to add a hover color like the main code I posted with an array of colors?

ONE MORE TRY WITH COLOR CODE THAT WORKS

```
$(function() {
   var forum = $('.main-content .statused tr'),i;
   var myColors = ["#000","#F00","#FF0","#FFF","#0F0","#00F"];
   var myHoverColors = ["#FF0000","#000","#FFF","#00FF00","#0000ff"];
   var i = 0;
     for(var j=0;j<forum.length;j++) {
       forumBG= forum[j];
       if(!forumBG) return;
          forum[j].style.background =myColors[i];
        if(i == myColors.length -1){
          i= 0;
       }else{
          i++;
      }
     }

  $(forum).on('mouseenter',function() {
      for(var j=0;j<forum.length;j++) {
         forumBG= forum[j];
          if(!forumBG) return;
       forum[j].style.background =myHoverColors[i];
         if(i == myColors.length -1){
          i= 0;
      }else{
          i++;
      }
    }
 });
    $(forum).on('mouseleave',function() {
      for(var j=0;j<forum.length;j++) {
      forumBG= forum[j];
       if(!forumBG) return;
      forum[j].style.background =myColors[i];
    if(i == myColors.length -1){
        i= 0;
     }else{
         i++;
     }
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: why don't you just use CSS?

Comment: Because the colors need to be different per tr element.

Comment: What do you mean by "destroys the code altogether"? What happens?

Comment: The backgrounds turn back to the original BG that the CSS was set to. I am posting another code, as I just retried my first code and the backgrounds are not changing colors. As well as the try again :?

Comment: try setting the second loop to `(var x=0; x <myHoverColors.length; x++)`

Comment: Tried it and it did nothing as well. I posted up the script that the backgrounds are actually changing now. Except on hover.

Comment: What are you trying to do, change the color of only the hovered row or change the color of all rows on hover?

Comment: Why in the world are you looping over every row on mouseover and setting the value? Shouldn't you be doing it for only the current row?

Comment: it appears that you are mixing JQuery with pure Javascript. try rewriting your script in pure javascript and you'll be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to convert your code into pure javascript because it appears that you are wrongly mixing JQuery with JavaScript.

```
var i, x, forum = document.getElementsByClassName('main-content')[0].getElementsByClassName('statused')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr'),
    myColors = ["#FFF", "#FFF", "#FFF", "#FFF", "#FFF", "#FFF", "#FFF", "#FFF", "#FFF", "#FFF", "#FFF", "#FFF", "#FFF", "#FFF", "#8A4B08", "#084B8A", "#8A0868", "#6A0888", "#21610B", "#8A0808", "#0B4C5F", "#5E610B", "#210B61"],
    myHoverColors = ["#FFE8E9", "#FFE8E9", "#FFE8E9", "FFE8E9", "#FFE8E9", "#FFE8E9", "#FFE8E9", "#FFE8E9", "#FFE8E9", "#FFE8E9", "#FFE8E9", "#FFE8E9", "#FFE8E9", "#FFE8E9", "#FF8000", "#0080FF", "#FF0080", "#A901DB", "#04B404", "#FF0000", "#01DFD7", "#FFFF00", "#4000FF"];
i = myColors.length--;
while (i--) { // backwards loop
 if (typeof forum[i] !== "undefined") forum[i].style.backgroundColor = myColors[i];
 // an undefined index will break the script
}

function handle(x) {
  forum[x].onmouseover = function () {
    forum[x].style.backgroundColor = myHoverColors[x];
  };
  forum[x].onmouseout = function () {
    forum[x].style.backgroundColor = myColors[x];
  };
}

x = forum.length--;
while (x--) handle(x);
```

And btw in your 'hover try', every time an element is hovered, you loop over every sister node; that's a **Big performance hit**
[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yq5f6/1).

Comment: I mixed jQuery because jQuerys $('.class') has a better handling than document.getElementsByClassName(); atleast this is what I was told :D

Comment: it makes it getting the class names much easier and simplier but you should avoid JavaScript just because of that becuase JavaScript is way faster than jQuery

Comment: granted this `$('.main-content .statused tr')` is much better than `document.getElementsByClassName('main-content')[0].getElementsByClassName('statused')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr')` lol

Comment: No I know JavaScript has a better response time than jQuery :) Though like you said granted it is better than the ClassName and TagName selectors in Javascript. Thank you and the code worked fine and dandy. I reading your code so I understand how everything was written. thank you

Comment: no prob. leave a comment if your having trouble personalizing  the code

Comment: Thanks for the support. I shouldn't have any problems though if I do I will comment. Or get ahold of you some how lol